# Como encontrar el contorno mas grande en OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

he estado trabajando en un codigo para el reconocimiento de manos. Pero me he encontrado con un problema que llevo tiempo teniendolo a la hora de hacer cualquier tipo de reconocimiento de imagen y es que me encuentro con pequeñas manchas que mi codigo detecta y en vez de seleccionar el contorno mas grande, lo que hace es escoger el contorno mas pequeño. Por lo que quiero saber si existe alguna forma de elegir el contorno mas grande.

He intentado buscar el area mas grande con el metodo de `cv2.contourArea`y tambien con el metodo de `cv2.arcLength`pero no me ha funcionado, porque lo que realmente me coge el programa son pequeños contornos.

Este es mi codigo:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

def SkinColorUpper (Hue,mult1,mult2):
    upper = [Hue,mult1*255,mult2*255]
    upper = np.array(upper)
    return upper

def SkinColorLower (Hue,mult1,mult2):
    lower = [Hue,mult1*255,mult2*255]
    lower = np.array(lower)
    return lower

direc = ('Fotos/A/1.jpg')
img = cv2.imread(direc,1)
# cv2.imshow("Imagen",img)
# cv2.waitKey(0)
heigth, width = img.shape[:2]
#print (img.shape)

start_row,start_col = int(0),int(0)
end_row, end_col = int(heigth), int(width*.3)
img = img[start_row:end_row,start_col:end_col]

hls = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)

mask = cv2.inRange(hls,SkinColorLower(0,0.2,0),SkinColorUpper(27,0.72,0.75))
#mask = cv2.inRange(hls,np.array([0,49,61]),np.array([20,255,127]))

blur = cv2.medianBlur(mask,5)

ret,edges = cv2.threshold(blur,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
#edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_CHRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(3,3))
edges= cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 
draw = cv2.drawContours(img,contours,-1,(255,0,0),3)
#print(contours)
cv2.imshow("mask",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)

for component in zip(contours,hierarchy):
    current_contour = component[0]
    # cv2.imshow("img_resize",current_contour)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(current_contour)
    p = cv2.arcLength(current_contour,True)
    epsilon = p*0.015
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(current_contour,epsilon,True)
    lados = len(approx)
    empty = np.zeros((h,w),np.uint8)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),1)
    roi = edges[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    empty[0:h,0:w]=roi
    edges=empty
    # cv2.imshow("Edges",edges)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)  
    img_resize = cv2.resize(edges,(150,150),interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
    ret, edges_res = cv2.threshold(img_resize,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    # cv2.imshow("img_resize",img_resize)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    contours_2,hierarchy_2 = cv2.findContours(edges_res.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    
    for component_2 in zip(contours_2,hierarchy_2):
        currentContour =  component_2[0]
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(currentContour)
        M = cv2.moments(currentContour)
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        A = cv2.contourArea(currentContour)
        p = cv2.arcLength(currentContour,True)
        aP=A/float(p*p)
        #print(M['m10'],M['m01'],M['m00'],cx,cy,A,p,aP)
        Hu = cv2.HuMoments(M)
        # print(Hu)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: el contorno en que formato lo obtienes? como puedes diferenciar un contorno pequeno en relacion a un grande?

Comment: Gracias, ya pude solucionarlo con ayuda de un amigo